# Javascript object property value comparison === vs indexOf

Tags: javascript

I have an object:

```
var myObj = {name: 'Tom', age : '25'}
```

Let's say I need to do something in my program if the name is `Tom`.

This is how I would normally do:

```
if(myObj.name === 'Tom'){
    //doSomething
}
```

However I could also make use of `indexOf` method:

```
if(myObj.name.indexOf('Tom') > -1){
    // dosomething
}
```

What I want to know is that :

Is using indexOf better than `===` operator ? Which one is better or is there still a better way to compare for an object's property value ?

Is there a performance overhead when using `===` operator when doing string comparisons ?

Oh btw, I'm using this in a node environment.

Comment: Have you read the documentation on `indexOf`?

Comment: "Tommy" is not "Tom" but contains "Tom"

Answer (score 3):

```
if(myObj.name.indexOf('Tom') > -1){ // is true
    // dosomething
}
```

will actually check for position of 'Tom' in the string stored in myObj.name, 
above if block will also be true for:

```
if(myObj.name.indexOf('To') > -1){ // is true
        // dosomething
    }
```

whereas

```
if(myObj.name === 'Tom'){ //is true
    //doSomething
}
```

this will compare complete strings myObj.name and 'Tom', myObj.name should be equal to 'Tom' otherwise this condition will not pass. this will fail for

```
if(myObj.name === 'To'){ //is false
        //doSomething
    }
```

> indexOf() compares searchElement to elements of the Array using strict
>   equality (the same method used by the === or triple-equals operator).

so imo, it will be better to use === here since you are searching for full string, because indexOf() might have extra overhead of comparing it against all substrings.

Comment: Agreed ! however considering in my program that i dont havt any substring situation and that I'm actually comparing the whole string 'Tom' in this case. what will be ideal to use ?

Comment: `indexOf() compares searchElement to elements of the Array using strict equality (the same method used by the === or triple-equals operator).` so imo, it will be better to use `===` here since you are searching for full string, because `indexOf()` might have extra overhead of comparing it against all substrings.

Answer (score 0):

indexOf returns the starting index of matching character .. 
indexOf doesn't tell you if original string is exactly equal to the original string.

```
'Blue Whale'.indexOf('Whale'); // returns 5 which means Whale exist in the string.
```

However on the other hand === operator will allow to precisely match the string.

```
'Blue Whale' === 'Whale';      // returns  false ;
```

So if you want to match the exact string use === operator with will also compare the type .

you can read the official documentation of indexOf

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Answer (score 0):

A strict comparison `===` is faster as all other kind of comparisons, because of not required type juggeling or like `indexOf` with comparison, where `indexOf` is iterating a string or an array for finding an index.

In this case, where you need just a value, then go for a direct comparison.

If you need to check for a substring, then go for `indexOf` or some other regular expression based checks.